# add input field with number increase & back to 2 after remove field

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the code to add an input field `if button` named "add" and when clicked the value number will increase (EX: number 1, number 2 & etc)

When I remove input field which is added, the number will continue to number 4, 5. if I click button "add" again, it should back to 1, 2, 3 ...

```js
$(function() {
  var ijk = 2;
  $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
    var add = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-1"><strong>Domain ' + ijk + ' </strong></div>' + '<div class="col-sm-4"><input name = "DynamicTextBox"  class="form-control" type="text" value = "" /></div>' + '<div class="col-sm-1"><button class="remove btn btn-danger">cancel</button></div></div> <br />';
    $("#TextBoxContainer").append(add);
    ijk++;
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest(".row").remove();
  });

});
```

```css
.col-sm-1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px
}

.col-sm-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 170px
}

.row {
  clear: both
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1"><strong>Domain 1</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" 2 id="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div id="TextBoxContainer">
  <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following snippet.

```js
$(function () {
   
      $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function (){
      var domainNumber = $('.row').length + 1; 
   var add = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-1"><strong>Domain '+ domainNumber +' </strong></div>' + '<div class="col-sm-4"><input name = "DynamicTextBox"  class="form-control" type="text" value = "" /></div>' + '<div class="col-sm-1"><button class="remove btn btn-danger">cancel</button></div></div> <br />';
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(add);
    
  });
                                
       $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
           $(this).closest(".row").remove();
       });
        
 });
```

```css
.col-sm-1{float:left; width:100px}
.col-sm-4{float:left;width:170px}
.row{clear:both}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-1"><strong>Domain 1</strong></div>
   <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" 2 id="">
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
   <button id="btnAdd"  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
       </div>
         
</div>
  <br>
          
   <div id="TextBoxContainer">
        <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
   </div>
```